# Target specific element of elementor for css

Tags: wordpress, html, css, elementor

[footer menu whose color I want to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQ80X.png) I am using elementor free version to build my wordpress website. I have written a css class in simple custom css plugin and apply this class on elementor elements. But it is only applied on div tag and not on ul or heading tag. Actually there are menu links on my footer with discs as a bullet and I want it to be bullet free. Therefore I have written a class as

```
.bottom{list-style-type:none;color:green;}
```

But only the color tag works on div elements and bullet color changes to green but list-style-type not works on ul and color also not works on h2 tag. How can I do this?

Comment: If you post the HTML code for the section you're trying to change via CSS, it will be easier for someone to help you with this. Also, Elementor usually likes you to use `selector` before whatever element you're trying to target when using their custom CSS box. 

(Ex.: `selector div.bottom p { /* my styles here */ }`)

Answer (score 0):

class that you give in elementor will always be assigned to the parent div of that element. you will have to target like this. hope it helps you

```
.bottom ul.primary-menu li.page_item.page-item-10
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but can you explain what is page item here

Comment: that is just an example. i was targeting my menu. and my li had `page-item` class.. if you can show me the html structure then i can help you with it.

Comment: I have added a picture of my menu whose color I want to change.

Comment: As everyone has his own class name. Therefore, I only ask you to explain your code so that I will know what are your classes in your code.

Comment: i think it is easily understandable `.bottom` will be the class name i will give.. `ul.primary-menu`  `li.page_item.page-item-10` will be the classname given to the `ul` and `li` respectively by the theme